# The data that except in the store function does not go to the db

Tags: laravel, database, forms, model, controller

i'm learning laravel.
I have to do a simple store function to create a new post. The form appears to work correctly but the data does not reach the DB.

There's my store function:

public function store(Request $request)

```
{
    $request->validate($this->validationRules);
    $formData = $request->all();

    $puzzle = new Puzzle();
    $puzzle->fill($formData);
    $puzzle->save();
    // $newPuzzle = Puzzle::create($formData);
    // return redirect()->route('puzzles.show', $newPuzzle->id);
}
```

My model:

class Puzzle extends Model

{

```
public $timestamps = false;
protected $fillable = [
    'title',
    'pieces',
    'image',
    'description',
    'brand',
    'price',
    'available',
    'quantity',
];
```

}
My form:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{route('puzzles.store')}}">
            @csrf
            <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="title" class="form-label">Title</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title" value="{{ old('title') }}">
            </div>

            <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="pieces" class="form-label">Pieces</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="pieces" name="pieces" value="{{ old('pieces')}}">
            </div>

            <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="description" class="form-label">Description</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="description" name="description" value="{{ old('description')}}">
            </div>

            <div class="mb-3 form-check">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="available">Available</label>
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="available" name="available" checked>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label for="quantity" class="form-label">Quantity</label>
                <input type="number" min="1" step="any" class="form-control" id="quantity" name="quantity">
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label for="price" class="form-label">Price</label>
                <input type="number" min="3.0" step="0.1" class="form-control" id="price" name="price">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
```

what am I doing wrong?
Thank you

Comment: can you add you form validation rule?

Comment: protected $validationRules = [
        'title'         =>  'min:5|max:250',
        'pieces'        =>  'numeric',
        'description'   =>  'min:5|max:500|',
        'price'         =>  'numeric',
        'available'     =>  'boolean',
        'quantity'      =>  'numeric',
    ];

Comment: there is issue in your data type sending by form. its stopped at validation . if you can attach you form data then I can help.

Comment: I made several attempts respecting the validations.
Even if for example I enter:
Title: TestTitle
Pieces: 100
Description: Test Description
Check Available
Quantity: 40
Price: 30
It doesn't give me any errors but the data doesn't go to the DB.

Comment: This is my migration:
  Schema :: create ('puzzles', function (Blueprint $ table) {
             $ table-> id ();
             $ table-> string ('title', 250);
             $ table-> integer ('pieces');
             $ table-> binary ('image') -> nullable ();
             $ table-> string ('description', 500);
             $ table-> string ('brand', 250) -> nullable ();
             $ table-> decimal ('price');
             $ table-> boolean ('available');
             $ table-> tinyInteger ('quantity') -> unsigned ();
         });

Comment: add the code to your question in a code block, not in the comments

Comment: If your controller gets behind the validation, then please post the `dd($formdata);`. That could give a hint what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make changes in your store function as per below

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validated = $request->validate([
       'title' => 'min:5|max:250',
       'pieces' => 'numeric',
       'description' => 'min:5|max:500',
       'price' => 'numeric',
       'available' => 'boolean',
       'quantity' => 'numeric',
    ]);
    
    $puzzle = Puzzle::create($request->only(
        'title', 'pieces', 'description', 'available', 'quantity', 'price'
    ));
    
    return redirect()->route('puzzles.show', $puzzle->id);
}
```

in `.env`

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=your_databse_name
DB_USERNAME=your_databse_user_name
DB_PASSWORD=your_databse_password
```

Comment: it doesn't work that way either. There is something wrong with validations:

protected $ validationRules = [
         'title' => 'min: 5 | max: 250',
         'pieces' => 'numeric',
         'description' => 'min: 5 | max: 500 |',
         'price' => 'numeric',
         'available' => 'boolean',
         'quantity' => 'numeric',
     ];

Comment: @SimoneTartaglia I've updated my answer. Now you can check with validation rules